# Is it safe to access/modify a shared variable in a signal handler?

Tags: perl, signals, opcode

In C, a signal handler may only access variable of type `volatile sig_atomic_t`. In perl, it safe (and atomic) to run this kind of signal handler ?

```
my $p = 0;

$SIG{CHLD} = sub {
    while (waitpid(-1, WNOHANG) > 0) {
        $p--;
    }
};
```

while my main thread is working with `$p` like doing `=`, `++` or `+=`.

I know that perl use [Safe-Signals](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlipc.html#Deferred-Signals-%28Safe-Signals%29) but is a simple `++` or `--` a single opcode ? What language operators are 1-opcode ?

By safe I mean that what are the operations atomic so that `$p` content doesn't get corrupted.

Comment: I think it may also depend on what is "safe."  I have some long-running (albeit non-critical) code that uses flow control based on assignments to a hash in the `SIGCHLD` handler.  Some socket reads do get interrupted by the signal handler (not because of assignment), but the handler itself never had trouble, nor caused anything unexpected.  Don't know about single opcodes though.

Comment: If the update of your hash is made of multiple opcodes (no idea), if you're working with it and then it gets interrupted in the middle, what would happen ?

Comment: I am pretty sure that adding a key-value pair to a hash is complex, and not one opcode.  If _that_ got interrupted no good things would come.  But I think that there is a very, very small chance that the handler's code that only assigns a ready value to a variable gets interrupted (I don't see how that can happen).  If it were doing more that's different. Please note: I do think that it's best to do as little as necessary.

Answer (score 4):

Under safe signals, assigning a sub to a signal in `%SIG` causes Perl to install a signal handler that just increments a counter. This counter is checked between Perl opcodes.<sup>[1]</sup> Only then is the Perl sub called.

Pre-increment, post-increment, pre-decrement and post-decrement are all Perl opcodes, so they won't get interrupted by a signal.

```
$ perl -MO=Concise,-exec -e'my $x; ++$x; --$x; $x++; $x--;'
1  <0> enter
2  <;> nextstate(main 1 -e:1) v:{
3  <0> padsv[$x:1,2] vM/LVINTRO
4  <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:1) v:{
5  <0> padsv[$x:1,2] sRM
6  <1> preinc vK/1
7  <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:1) v:{
8  <0> padsv[$x:1,2] sRM
9  <1> predec vK/1
a  <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:1) v:{
b  <0> padsv[$x:1,2] sRM
c  <1> preinc[t2] vK/1
d  <;> nextstate(main 2 -e:1) v:{
e  <0> padsv[$x:1,2] sRM
f  <1> predec[t3] vK/1
g  <@> leave[1 ref] vKP/REFC
-e syntax OK
```

We would also have to see how `$p` is used outside of the signal handler to determine if it's safe or not. For example, you'd have a problem if the code outside the signal handler did the following, because that could be interrupted.

```
$p = $p - 1;
```

---

This is safe:

```
my %children;

$SIG{CHLD} = sub {
   local ($?, $!, $^E);
   while ( ( my $pid = waitpid(-1, WNOHANG) ) > 0 ) {
      my $child = $children{$pid}
         or next;   # ?!?

      $child->{exit_status} = $?;
   }
};    

while (1) {
   ...

   for my $pid (keys(%children)) {
      my $child = $children{$pid};
      defined( my $exit_status = $child->{exit_status} )
         or next;

      delete($children{$pid});

      ...
   }

   ...
}
```

---

1. I think it has been made even less granular in more recent versions of Perl.

Comment: Updated my answer.